# inserting ads after every 7th post in wordpress home page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to place google ads between every 7 posts in my homepage and category pages of wordpress site.

i have found this code on WordPress forum and tried myself by putting it it didn't worked. i am not sure how to use this code in my theme.
the code i found is this.

```
if ( have_posts() ) : $count = 0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
//before 
if (($count>1) && ($count%5 == 0) ){ ?>
  <div>
    [adcode] 
  </div> <?
          } $count++;
```

here is the relative code from index.php of my theme.

```
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php 

                if ( floatval(get_bloginfo('version')) < "3.6" ) {
                    //old post formats before they got built into the core
                     get_template_part( 'includes/post-templates-pre-3-6/entry', get_post_format() ); 
                } else {
                    //WP 3.6+ post formats
                     get_template_part( 'includes/post-templates/entry', get_post_format() ); 
                } ?>

            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

i want to know how do i place the code according to my the upper code of index.php. thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a **$counter** then to display based on it the adcode. So the final code for you will be this one:

```
$counter = 1;
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php 
if($counter % 7 == 0) {
?>
[adcode] 
<?php
}

if ( floatval(get_bloginfo('version')) < "3.6" ) {
    //old post formats before they got built into the core
     get_template_part( 'includes/post-templates-pre-3-6/entry', get_post_format() ); 
} else {
    //WP 3.6+ post formats
     get_template_part( 'includes/post-templates/entry', get_post_format() ); 
} ?>

<?php $counter++; endwhile; endif; ?>
```

We just increment the $counter, and display the **[adcode]** after each seven posts.

Comment: this worked but only for the first 7 post. i mean 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 [ad] 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16........ why it didn't showed ad after 14th post.

Comment: Strange, should work and for next posts, because from seven to seven the counter modulo will be 0. Maybe there is somehow pagination involved, how many posts do you have per page?

Comment: there are 10 posts per page and i am using infinite scroll. which load 10 posts per scroll.

Comment: So this is why it does not work, it loads the next posts via ajax. The solution will be for the next posts to add the ads code with jQuery, or javascript, or to find a php call that return the result, and add there the code

Comment: it will be hard for me to understand so i will leave it here. thanks for your help. stay happy and blessed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming [adcode] is a shortcode due to the square brackets. This code is untested.

```
if(have_posts()) : $count = 0; while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php 

if ( $count % 7 == 0 ) {
    do_shortcode('[adcode]');
}

if ( floatval(get_bloginfo('version')) < "3.6" ) {
//old post formats before they got built into the core
    get_template_part( 'includes/post-templates-pre-3-6/entry', get_post_format() ); 
} else {
//WP 3.6+ post formats
    get_template_part( 'includes/post-templates/entry', get_post_format() ); 
} ?>

<?php $count++; endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: [adcode] is not short code. it mean that the ad code will be here. your code give this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) in C:\wamp\www\wp\wp-content\themes\salient\index.php on line 96. the line 96 is <?php endwhile; endif; ?>